# unable to run locally orchard azure project ysod fresh off sources

Tags: azure, orchardcms

I am trying to run locally Orchard.Azure.CloudService project without any code changes to the official stable release 1.7.1 (58c21815). full source address is @ https://git01.codeplex.com/orchard .

Here is the steps to reproduce the error:

1. launch the Orchard.Azure solution
2. select "Debug" build
3. click on press F5 start debugging
4. the page will show "Server Error in '/' Application."

   None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardShell' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Orchard.Mvc.Routes.IRoutePublisher routePublisher' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Func`1[Autofac.Features.OwnedInstances.Owned`1[Orchard.Environment.IOrchardShellEvents]], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Orchard.Mvc.Routes.IRouteProvider], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Orchard.WebApi.Routes.IHttpRouteProvider], Orchard.Mvc.Routes.IRoutePublisher, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Orchard.Mvc.ModelBinders.IModelBinderProvider], Orchard.Mvc.ModelBinders.IModelBinderPublisher, Orchard.Tasks.ISweepGenerator)'.
   Source Error:

   Line 111:            var shellScope = _shellContainerFactory.CreateContainer(settings, blueprint);

   Line 112:

   Line 113:            return new ShellContext {

   Line 114:                Settings = settings,

   Line 115:                Descriptor = descriptor,

   Source File:  c:\projects\orchard\src\Orchard\Environment\ShellBuilders\ShellContextFactory.cs    Line:  113 
   `

   ... "

   ```
   Windows 8, x64
   VS2012.3 Azure SDK 2.1
   source code version hash: 58c21815
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue that the solution can't run in the emulator. This is caused by the structure of the solution, and the fact the emulator doesn't run the cspack file. This script is used to copy modules and themes into the package for Azure deployment. When the emulator runs it simply mounts the Orchard.Azure.Web project which is almost empty and doesn't have all the files necessary to run the solution.

See this [discussion](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/459308) on CodePlex for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you should be running that solution but the main Orchard solution.

ie, you don't need to develop specifically for Azure, just deploy for Azure.

I think ^_^

Comment: If that is the case, how do it debug the Orchard Azure project. Since there are specific lines of code that are related to Azure, they have to be debug-able.