# Themes in Orchard hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, orchardcms, azure-cloud-services

I've been setting up Orchard 1.8 in an Azure Cloud Service. I've got it working, but I'm now confused as to how to use it.

Installing themes via the gallery fails silently. The devs say this is because Orchard on Azure doesn't support the theme gallery, and suggest adding new themes to the project and uploading a new package (https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/453688). Ignoring that this requires any designers that want to make minor CSS changes now need Visual Studio, access to the entire source code, and then wait through a 20 minute deploy, this just doesn't seem possible.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443077/unable-to-run-locally-orchard-azure-project-ysod-fresh-off-sources) explains how the Azure emulator doesn't work with Orchard. So now I'm confused; what is the expected workflow for a brand new Orchard site hosted on Azure if I can't make changes to the site in production or staging but cannot run it locally either. I'm aware I could run it without the Azure emulator on regular IIS but that seems to be too far removed from the production environment to be a good test.

I was drawn to Orchard originally because it had great documentation and supports MVC Web API, but this seems so fundamental that now I'm not so sure. I feel like every time something goes wrong they'll always be doubt whether it's working as designed or if there is an Azure idiosyncrasy going on.

I'd love to hear from anyone who's had an Orchard site from scratch in Azure, I'm hoping I've just missed something simple with this.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Why use a cloud service?

Comment: I have a project in mind that may need them. I'm not sure but I'd rather setup on a cloud service rather than migrate later when it's much more painful. But more simply... why not? Cloud Services are officially supported and I'm familiar with them.

Comment: Why not? Because they are a million times clunkier and hard to use than Azure web sites. What is the specific feature of cloud services that you need and that web sites don't have?

Comment: I probably don't *need* a cloud service. I never gave it any thought. The Orchard guides did not mention any preference or list any downsides to either option. As I have already used cloud services it felt like the natural thing to do. I mean no disrespect but it seems this area lacks focus. There is a theme gallery - which isn't recommended, a module installer - which is ill-advised, and a cloud service installation - that can't really be used. So why do they exist? Is there a list of features that I should avoid? Why tell people cloud services are supported and question them if they use it?

Comment: Some people have personal web sites where they don't really care about uptime, and so they can take the risk of installing modules and themes in production. Others like the convenience of the gallery integration on their dev machines. There are lots of valid scenarios for installing from the gallery, but it would be irresponsible not to warn users about installing code directly in production on a more serious site, no matter what the platform is, Orchard or other.

Comment: Cloud services are a relatively old technology that was all that was available on Azure when Orchard first came out. Web Sites didn't even exist. As Web Sites came out and became more fully-featured, we switched our recommendation to them, because they are so much easier and have no downside. Some documentation still needs to be updated however. Contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You should never install modules or themes on a production server. Instead, install those on your dev machine, build the package and then deploy. If you don't want to deal with the heaviness of cloud services, don't use cloud services. Azure Web Sites are about a million times easier to use, and they work great. They allow for what you're asking for.

Comment: I get the point they're trying to make by not allowing changes like that on production, but I can't make them locally because (as the devs recognise) Orchard will not run on Azure emulator. It seems the only thing to do is upload a package without ever seeing it work. Is this really the recommended way of doing things?

Comment: Then use web sites. That should solve your problem, and it is also the recommended way to run Orchard on Azure.

Comment: You can also do most of your development without azure, then publish to staging and test it before pushing that to production.